# Where should I add autoload cookies in my Emacs Lisp package? Is there a definitive guide?

Tags: elisp, autoload

I maintain a somewhat popular Emacs package ([ido-ubiquitous](https://github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/ido-ubiquitous)), and I would like to add the `;;;###autoload` comments to my package so that it does not need to be loaded until its mode is activated. I attempted this a while ago with the same package, and it resulted in a number of cryptic errors that only occurred when the package was autoloaded, so I removed all the autoload stuff and the problems went away. I'd like to try again, but only if I can find definitive documentation on how to do it so I don't end up introducing the same bugs again.

So is there a definitive guide to adding autoload cookies to an Emacs Lisp package?

EDIT: Looking at my Git logs for my package, I see a couple of commits referring to autoloads:

- [283f9e9](https://github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/ido-ubiquitous/commit/283f9e9) Remove unnecessary autoloads
- [66b782f](https://github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/ido-ubiquitous/commit/66b782f) Autoload default values of override variables
- [f6086e5](https://github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/ido-ubiquitous/commit/f6086e5) Autoload fix
- [0eed206](https://github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/ido-ubiquitous/commit/0eed206) Remove unnecessary autoload cookie

These commits show that I was really not sure what to add autoloads to. In particular, f6086e5 and 66b782f shows that I thought I should autoload custom variables, and concluded that I also needed to autoload the `defconst` forms that defined their default values. If I recall correctly, this was in response to a void-variable error because the autoloaded defcustom didn't have access to the non-autoloaded default value ([issue link](https://github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/ido-ubiquitous/issues/16)). Finally, in 283f9e9 I had a vision of the future and took Stefan's advice by removing all autoloads except for the one on the minor mode definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `;;;###autoload` cookies simply mark code which needs to be lifted into a `<pkg>-autoloads.el` file.  This file is then loaded eagerly on startup, but that can be done quickly because it's a much smaller file.  So you typically only need such a cookie on the few main entry points.  E.g. I'd start by only putting one such cookie on `ido-ubiquitous-mode`.

Comment: Is is necessary to put autoload cookies for things like `defcustom`s and other interactive functions (only one of those in this case)?

Comment: It is generally undesirable to put autoload cookies on variables.  It is useful/necessary on interactive functions which might be called before any other (i.e. might be called when org-ubiquitous.el is not yet loaded).

Comment: What about `defadvice` ?

Comment: An autoload cookie is normally not needed for defadvice, because the advice normally only needs to be installed/activated once the package is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for autoloading is here:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Autoload` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Are you able to give any details on the errors you encountered?

Comment: I guess what I mean is that I know how to mark things as autoloaded, but I'm not sure *which* things I'm supposed to mark as autoloaded. The info page that you reference really only addresses the first issue. In any case, when I have time I'll dig out an example error.